# "couldn't be multiplied by an non integer - float" error in Python

Tags: python

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90, 97, 75, 92],
    "quizzes": [88, 40, 94],
    "tests": [75, 90]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100, 92, 98, 100],
    "quizzes": [82, 83, 91],
    "tests": [89, 97]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0, 87, 75, 22],
    "quizzes": [0, 75, 78],
    "tests": [100, 100]
}

def get_average(student):
    weight = 0
    total = 0
    for item in student:
        if item == "homework":
            weight = .1
        elif item == "quizzes":
            weight = .3
        elif item == "tests":
            weight = .6
        else:
            weight = 0
        total += student[item] * weight

    return total

get_average(tyler)
```

What is going on here?  It is giving me an error saying that

> `student[item]` couldn't be multiplied by an non integer -  float

Comment: try adding some print statements so you can see what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to multiply strings and lists with float numbers which is not possible.

```
student[item] * weight
```

try something like this:

```
def get_average(student):
    weight = 0
    total = 0
    for item,val in student.items(): #use dict.items() if you need to wrk on both key and values
        if item == "homework":
            weight = .1
        elif item == "quizzes":
            weight = .3
        elif item == "tests":
            weight = .6
        else:
            continue    # no need of weight = 0 simple move on to next item
                        # continue statement jumps the loop to next iteration
        total += (float(sum(val)) / len(val)) * weight
    return total

print get_average(tyler)  #prints 79.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't multiply the list by the weight, first get the average! add the following lines in your for loop:

```
averaged = sum(student[item])/float(len(student[item]))
total += averaged * weight
```

so now this is your for loop:

```
for item in student:
        if item != "Name":
            averaged = sum(student[item])/float(len(student[item]))
        if item == "homework":
            weight = .1
        elif item == "quizzes":
            weight = .3
        elif item == "tests":
            weight = .6
        else:
            weight = 0
        total += averaged * weight
```

Comment: This is wrong, you're trying to do `sum` on string.(`student["name"]` is a string)